# My question is about multiple % operator in Like command in mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

What does `%%%s%%` mean? Also what does `%(author) mean?

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM new WHERE author LIKE '%%%s%%' "%(author)
```

Comment: Is syntax valid?

Comment: yes it works @CS_noob

Answer (score 2):

In a SQL `LIKE` pattern, `%` matches any sequence of characters. So if you write:

```
WHERE author LIKE '%Jones%'
```

it will match an `author` that contains `Jones` anywhere in it.

This code is also using the Python `%` operator for string formatting, that's what `%(author)` is for. This formatting operator looks for formatting specifications in the string that begin with `%` -- `%s` means to substitute the value of the corresponding string from the tuple `(author)`.

And since `%` has special meaning in the format string, you need to double it to produce a literal `%` character.

So if you do:

```
author = "Jones"
```

then the value of

```
"SELECT * FROM new WHERE author LIKE '%%%s%%' "%(author)
```

will be:

```
"SELECT * FROM new WHERE author LIKE '%Jones%'"
```